# Javascript-REGEX

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a Regex to match patterns existing in multiple lines. The code is as follows:

```
(.*Action name.*\n.*Action status.*)[\n+]*(good)
```

The text string is as follows:

> Workflow name:icl_prd_db_logs
>   Action name:backup
>   Action status:failed
>   hi
>   how r u
>   good
>   perfect
>   Code successfully completed
>   Another code failed

Now I can use one `\n` if I want to match `Action name` and `Action status` because those are sequential lines. But, if I want to match a line which exists after several lines then a single `\n` will not work. In other words, how can I use `\n` multiple times something like `[\n]`+ or [\n]*+ or `[\n+](.*)`.

I don't want to use any arrays just I need a single line code which can map all the existing pattern matches. Does anyone know how to do that?

In the above-mentioned code, I am trying to search `good` pattern which is two lines away from the `Action status` line so I have tried to use `[\n+]*` but it doesn't work at all. Can anyone help me to sort out this code?

Comment: There are a lot of questions on SO that presume that regular expressions can do more than they can. When someone wants a magic catch-all regular expression that can be very complicated and even more difficult to maintain. Whereas a solution that involves several lines of code or a few regular expressions can be more easily understood and more easily maintained. Is there a reason why "I need a single line code"?

Comment: Of course looking for multiple _consecutive_ line breaks doesn’t work, because you don’t _have any_ of those here. Those lines all contain characters _before_ the line break.

Answer (score 2):

You can write `(.*\n.*)*` for multipal line regex. So finally your regex is `(.*Action name.*(\n)+.*Action status.*)(.*\n.*)*(good)`.

https://regex101.com/r/yGpz5v/1

Comment: Thanks for the quick support Pathik. I have succesfully tested this pattern match condition in my environment. I am facing one more issue for large amounts of data in log file and due to that there is an error called 'Catastrophic backtracking' issue.